# determining if the scrollbar is overlay or legacy

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have  a scrollview which has a customview as a documentview.
The size of the customview is calculated in my code as

Height of customview = height of scrollview - height of scroller

my app is compiled with 10.5 and runs well on 10.5/10.6
It also runs well on 10.7 if external mouse is used.

But if I run on 10.7 and i use the built in multitouch trackpad on lion the scrollbar is a overlay.
So the height should be 
Height of customview = height of scrollview

Now what should i do to take care of this issue..

-thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ask NSScroller for [the height of a scroller of the relevant control size and scroller style](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScroller_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSScroller/scrollerWidthForControlSize%3ascrollerStyle%3a), the latter of which you should [get from your scroll view](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/scrollerStyle).

Note that the correct scroller style can change at any time, such as whenever a mouse or trackball is plugged in or unplugged. You may want to observe for [the relevant notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScroller_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification) and redo your calculation whenever it comes in.